# Removing Groups within an Array in Kineticjs

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I am trying to remove elements of an array which contains either Groups(containing shapes) or simply Shapes(line, Rect, Circle etc) as its elements. My function is something like below:

```
deleteSelectedShape = function () {
var i,
    shapeObj,
    selectedObjects = currentContext.getSelectedObjects(),
    shapeLayer = currentContext.getShapeLayer();

   if (selectedObjects && selectedObjects.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < selectedObjects.length; i += 1) {
        shapeObj = selectedObjects[i];
        // shapeObj.remove(); results same error as mentioned at last

             if (shapeObj.nodeType === "Group") {
                    shapeObj.destroyChildren();
             }
              else{
                 shapeObj.destroy();
               }
            }
        }

         selectedObjects = [];
         shapeLayer.draw();
   };
```

I tried this also

```
  if (shapeObj.nodeType === "Group") {
            var childs = [];
            childs = shapeObj.getChildren();
            for (var j = 0; j < childs.length; j++) {
                childs[j].remove();
            }
        }
        else{
             shapeObj.remove();
           }
        }  
    }
```

Here Individual shapes are getting deleted but if there is group in array, it is giving error :

```
    TypeError: this.getParent(...) is undefined in Kineticjs file
```

Please suggest me proper idea. Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

One problem: When removing items from an array, you have to iterate through that array in reverse.

```
var i=selectedObjects.length-1;

while( i-- >=0 ){

    var shapeObj = selectedObjects[i];

    if (shapeObj.nodeType === "Group") {
        shapeObj.destroyChildren();
    }else{
        shapeObj.destroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: There is not any problem with deleting any no. of selected shapes. But if there is a group in the array, only then it throws error as above.So i wanted to know how to delete that group from array along with other shapes ? Looping is not the problem. Thanks !!!